# Why am I getting, 'Unable to write stream to' error when uploading asset?

Tags: assets, image, storage

I set up Fortrabbit object storage but when I go to upload an image in 'add asset' I get this error in a pop up;

Unable to write stream to 'fileName'

When I try to upload it with 'upload asset' the loading bar just hangs there until I refresh.

Is there something wrong with my filesystem/asset paths or even permissions?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Many thanks,
Zack

Answer (score 1):

Frank from fortrabbit here. It's probably something about your setup. More details would be required to understand the issue. We also have a client support chat to discuss individual config problems.

For the records: The fortrabbit Object Storage requires this plugin:
https://github.com/fortrabbit/craft-object-storage - there are also instructions how to configure. You can test access from our local machine as well.